# Symfony propel addAnd

Tags: symfony, propel

I dont know propel.  I need to convert this propel code.  In this code the strings `$array[$i]` will concordinate with `$array[0]` or the last string of `$array[$i]` only stored in this `$array[0]`.

```
$array[0]->addAnd($array[$i]);
```

Comment: To convert *this propel code* to what? Which version of Symfony? All in all your question isn't really clear to understand ..

Comment: i need to convert this to symfony 2.0.this line is inside the for loop ($array[0]->addAnd($array[$i]);)

Answer (score 0):

The `addAnd(...)` method adds another condition (a Propel `Criterion` object) to the `WHERE` clause in the resulting SQL query - in your case, that query is represented by `$array[0]`. Since we don't know what `$array[$i]` is (although it is most likely a Propel `Criterion`) we can't really say what the result will be, but it will append `AND {string representation of $array[$i]}` to the existing SQL. You can check the [Propel API docs](http://api.propelorm.org/1.3.0/runtime/propel-util/Criterion.html#methodaddAnd) for info on the `addAnd(...)` method.